# Bootstrap Date picker doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap date picker component in my html and can't get it to display the data. I would assume i have put it wrong into the code.

```js
$('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    multidate: true,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    toggleActive: true,
    defaultViewDate: { year: 1977, month: 04, day: 25 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your date picker initialization code

```
$('#sandbox-container .input-daterange').datepicker({
    ....
});
```

Since you have this html

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

The initialization code above would target the container div (the one with `class="input-daterange input-group"`) instead of the two textboxes inside it, so that's why the date picker doesn't show up. You need to change the initialization code above to this

```
$('#datepicker .input-sm').datepicker({
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to put jquery.js before bootstrap js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```